# How to add an "order by" clause in PHP to a MySQL query (unexpected T_Error...)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code...

```
<?
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products where category =". $ID ;
    $result = @mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>

        <table width="810" valign="center">
            <tr height="100px">
                <td width="150px"><img src="<?php echo($row['imagethumb']) ?>" width="150" height="100" border="0" /></td>

                <td width="200px"><h3><a href='item.php?id=<?php echo($row['id']) ?>'> <?php echo($row['title']) ?></a></h3></td>

                <td width="200px"><h4>$<?php echo($row['price']) ?></h4>  </td>

                <td><h4><a href="<?php echo($row['cartlink']) ?>"><span class="addtocart"></span></a></h4></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<?
    }
?>
```

And I want to sort my results by price. So far I haven't been able to get ORDER BY 'price' ASC to work.

Comment: Please prvide the full error you are receiving. This looks like a basic PHP syntax error.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/33/7377933/html/updates/products/index.php on line 51

Comment: This only happens when I add ORDER BY price ASC After "where category =". $ID"

Comment: And we have to guess how you appended that? Too localized. Also consider using prepared statements, makes the variable/string concatenation redundant (which is what you obviously have trouble with).

Comment: Remove everything from "$result = (...)" and you will still have the same error. This is not a MySQL-related issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products where category ='".$ID."' order by columnname ASC " ;
```

Comment: This works, sorry for my incompetence! Thank you all very much!